# Why is my dynamic dropdown list not working?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, dynamic, dropdown

The drop down list is suppose to fetch records from a column in another table but currently there are no records appearing. Also, i would need an option in the drop down list that says "others" for the users to key in if they cannot find what they want in the list. 
Here are my codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showfield(name){
    if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Please Specify: <input type="text" name="other" />';
    else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
    }
    </script>   
<label for="issue_type">Issue Type</label>
<?php 
include ("../db/dbConn.php"); 
$sql = "SELECT issue_type FROM issue where deleted =0"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo '<select class ="form-control" type="text" name="issue_type" id="issue_type" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" >';
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
 echo "<option value='".$row['issue_type']."'>".$row['issue_type']."      </option>"; 
    } 
   echo "</select>";

?>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: can you check the query to fire directly on mysql whether it is returning any results. For an additional option of other you can use <option value="Other">Other</option> outside while loop

Comment: hi did you mean that i should try typing "SELECT issue_type FROM issue where deleted =0" into mysql?if thats the case i have tried it and it returned the results that i wanted. but the dropdown list does not fetch these records.....please help..

Comment: Can you check "echo mysql_num_rows($result)" in the script what it returns.

Comment: still nothing... the records still does not appear in the dropdown list...do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

assign html section to a variable, then echo it. try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showfield(name){
if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Please Specify: <input type="text" name="other" />';
else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
}
</script>   
<label for="issue_type">Issue Type</label>
<?php 
include ("../db/dbConn.php"); 
$sql = "SELECT issue_type FROM issue where deleted =0"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$htm = '';
$htm .='<select class ="form-control" type="text" name="issue_type" id="issue_type" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" >';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
$htm .="<option value='".$row['issue_type']."'>".$row['issue_type']."      </option>"; 
} 
$htm .= "<option value='Other'>Other</option>"; // add other option
$htm .="</select>";
echo $htm;
?>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: hi i have tried using your codes but it still does not work.. the only option in the dropdown list is "others"...

Comment: Are you sure $result is not empty and it contains key `issue_type` ? did you try print_r($result) ?

Comment: hi sorry but can you guide me to how i can check?because my $sql statement has no error....

Comment: try `echo '<pre />';print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result,TRUE)); die;` before while loop and check if there is `issue_type` field.

Comment: Hi, i tried that but it doesnt seem to work. i am not able to select the drop down and the rest of my fields have disappeared! please help :(

Comment: it's because we used `die;` to stop execution, try commenting the above code,.Did the above code returned any result ? If not you are not getting any result and that will be the reason.

Comment: The dropdown list still just returns 'others'.

Comment: seems like you are not getting any result in $result variable or it is returning result in incorrect format. That's why control not goes inside while loop. If you get result then it will work. Correct that portion first.

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea i can actually correct it? give that the bulk of my codes are already posted here! Would appreciate it so much! thanks

Comment: my friend, that part is up to you :) . bcz i don't know how the table "issue" looks like and what value `$result` returns. If it returns array of values with `issue_type` field in it, then my code will work.